# What is the type of this encoding?

Tags: php, encryption, encoding, character-encoding

i have an file is encoded to this format what type of this encoding please?

```
<?php
/*********************/
/*                   */
/*  Version : 5.1.0  */
/*  Author  : RM     */
/*  Comment : 071223 */
/*                   */
/*********************/

echo "ELF\x01\x02\x01\x00\x00\x00
```

Answer (score 2):

That's an [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) header - a linux/bsd/solaris/bunch of others executable file.

Answer (score 2):

The `"\x01"` is a string with C-style character escaping. PHP supports it in its double quoted strings too.
See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double